# Ubuntu MATE 16.04 sends me back to login page when waking from suspend

Tags: unity, gnome, login, suspend, ubuntu-mate

For some reason, whenever I wake my computer from suspend and log in, five seconds later it sends me back to a login screen, but its different. instead of the classic GNOME 2 login screen, it sends me to the default GNOME 3 login screen with the default orange Ubuntu background instead of the MATE green one. it also only has one line on it called Password with a text box, and an unlock button. No name text box, no switch user button. the top bar is default GNOME 3 with my name in the top right and the time in the middle, nothing else. sometimes when I enter the password it logs in, but then sends me back there. I've never been prompted more than 3 times. I had the default unity launcher installed, but that uses a different login manager. I uninstalled Unity and even booted from an earlier kernel, but it's still there. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks! Here is the output of `apt-cache policy gnome-screensaver`

```
gnome-screensaver:
  Installed: 3.6.1-7ubuntu4
  Candidate: 3.6.1-7ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 3.6.1-7ubuntu4 500
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy gnome-screensaver`. On my 16.04 LTS MATE - gnome-screensaver is not installed. And after waiting from suspend I get MATE lock screen (gray with Leave Message, Switch User, Cancel, Unlock buttons).